# How to convert a jpg into a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0?

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg, bmp, file-conversion

I've tried using image magic but it converts the image into a compressed format and most of the online conversion tools are also doing the same thing.
Is there some way i could achieve this in image magic or anywhere else?

Answer (score 3):

Use the ImageMagick "-compress none" option to prevent compression, and use "-define bmp:format=bmp4" to force BMP4.0:

```
convert in.jpg -define bmp:format=bmp4 -compress none out.bmp
```

You can omit defining the bmp4 format because that's the currently the default BMP output format for ImageMagick anyhow.

Add "-alpha on" if you need RGBA instead of RGB pixels.

See the ImageMagick documentation for the [-compress](http://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#compress) and [-define](http://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#define) options.